# Reading and writing files causes "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" error

Tags: vba

I'm very new to coding so my code is very basic but I am trying to rewrite a file using an item selected from a list box. The code is a recreation of my full code so it's not as thorough but I want to be able to change the "availability" of a product for a website (In theory because this is not a professional project). When I try to read or write the file an error message comes up saying "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

```
Dim FileRewrite As String = "FileRewrite.txt"
Dim ValidateID As Boolean
Dim Read As String
Dim IDR As String
Dim YNR As String
Private Sub TxtBxID_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TxtBxID.TextChanged
    If TxtBxID.Text.Length = 2 Then
        ValidateID = True
    Else
        ValidateID = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnAdd.Click
    Dim ID As String
    Dim YN As String
    Dim Writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FileRewrite, True)

    If ValidateID = True Then
        ID = TxtBxID.Text
        If CBxYN.Checked = True Then
            YN = "YES"
        Else
            YN = "NO "
        End If

        Writer.WriteLine(LSet(ID, 3) & LSet(YN, 3))
        Writer.Close()

        LstBxItems.Items.Clear()
        Dim Reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FileRewrite, True)
        Do While Reader.Peek >= 0
            LstBxItems.Items.Add(Reader.ReadLine)
        Loop
        Reader.Close()

    Else
        MsgBox("Please enter a 2 digit ID")
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub BtnChange_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnChange.Click
    Dim ItemToChange As String
    Dim Reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FileRewrite, True)

    ItemToChange = LstBxItems.SelectedItem
    IDR = Mid(ItemToChange, 1, 3)
    YNR = Mid(ItemToChange, 4, 6)

    Do While Reader.Peek >= 0
        Read = Reader.ReadLine
        Writer()
    Loop
    Reader.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Writer()
    Dim Writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FileRewrite, True)
    If Mid(Read, 1, 3) = IDR Then
        If YNR = "YES" Then
            YNR = "NO "
        Else
            YNR = "YES"
        End If
        Writer.WriteLine(LSet(IDR, 3) & LSet(YNR, 3))
        Writer.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

I expect the availability of the product in the file to change from yes to no or no to yes but the reader and writer will not work

Comment: Which line gives you the Error ? Is it possible that the file is open in Background in Notepad or any other software ?

Comment: The problem is you are reading a file and at the same time you try to write the file

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to the file while looping through the same file to read via `Reader.Peek`